# Ubuntu server to act as API gateway

Tags: proxy, gateway

A service provider requires that all HTTPS calls to its API come from a IP whitelist, this can be a problem when you're hosted in cloud.

So I would like to setup an existing Linux (Ubuntu) Server, with a static IP in the middle, to forward requests and responses *as is*, back and forth between our app and the API.

The only change in my app's configuration should be Ubuntu's IP instead of the API one.

**What is the easiest linux approach to accomplish this?**

Comment: Assuming "API" means "REST API via HTTP calls", then the simplest approach is some http proxy (there's a wide range of choices), or maybe even just ssh port forwarding if it's only for a single client.

Comment: @dirkt yes, HTTP(s) calls to REST/SOAP API. I saw some proxies examples, these all assumed some proxy configuration on the client. Any link to a _no client config_ example?

Comment: @neurino you should search for a *reverse* proxy, where the proxy configuration is in the server (e.g., https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: And make sure you **properly secure** the reverse proxy (whatever choice you make, nginx is certainly an option), so only "your" clients can connect - you are circumventing the whitelist of the original service, and if the whole world can now connect to it through your proxy, your proxy's IP will soon disappear from the whitelist.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt I will, also there are other security measures already in place on the service itself — user, password, token, etc